# JWTGenerateCommand::handle() does not exist

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

I am using Laravel 5.4 and [JWT Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki) Library for user authentication in API development. After installation while i am running `php artisan jwt:generate` then it throws me error of

```
Method Tymon\JWTAuth\Commands\JWTGenerateCommand::handle() does not exist
```

Any idea what i am missing ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This error generally display when you install jwt package in laravel 5.5 version. then after you set service providers and run following command.

```
php artisan jwt:generate
```

then you seen this error message in terminal.

how to resolve it? simple follow this step

**Step - 1 Re-install package**

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source
```

or the following is a new release package use laravel 6.X

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.*
```

in this developement version this errors fixed.

**Step - 2 Set Service Provider**

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class to 
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class
],
```

**Step - 3 Generate key**

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

i found this solution from here https://laravelcode.com/post/method-tymonjwtauthcommandsjwtgeneratecommandhandle-does-not-exist

Comment: Currently first step should be "composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.*" and then proceed with second and third step

Answer (score 5):

Go to JWTGenerateCommand.php file located in vendor/tymon/src/Commands and paste this method

```
public function handle() { $this->fire(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's never a great idea to change anything in the vendor folder but the there's two ways to deal with this ...

1. Generate a random string yourself and just change the value in the JWT config file.
2. Go to Tymon\JWTAuth\Commands\JWTGenerateCommand and change the fire method to handle.

Answer (score 3):

go to given file path

**vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Commands/JWTGenerateCommand.php**

change function name

public function fire() to ***public function handle()***

run command:

**php artisan jwt:generate**

Comment: May be your solution is working but ideally editing vendor/sources is not recommended.

Comment: This is working for me. But @Chintan7027 said that right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm publishing this answer because I have crash in this error more than one time.

The only solution I found that it works with Laravel 5.6 is the following:

- Add "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.1" to composer.json and `run composer update`
- Open `config/app.php` and add the following:

**config/app.php**:

```
 'providers' => [
   /*
   * JWT Service Provider...
   */
   Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
 ],
 'aliases' => [
   'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
   'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,
 ],
```

- Execute:

  php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
- Finally, execute: `php artisan jwt:secret`

After all that, when I hit my endpoint for login I got the following exception:

```
Class Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\NamshiAdapter does not exist
```

This was fixed by:

- Open `config/jwt.php` and change the following:

**config/jwt.php**:

```
'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class,
'auth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\Illuminate::class,
'storage' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\Illuminate::class,
```

Finally, note that in order to work your User model should be defined as follows:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
     ...
     public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can advise one solution. Go to JWTGenerateCommand.php file located in vendor/tymon/src/Commands and paste this part of code public function handle() { $this->fire(); }

I know this is not an elegant solution, but it works. I hope this might help until official fix arrive.

[see here for more info](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1298)

Answer (score 0):

Change fire() function to handle() in this path
vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/commands/JWTGenerateCommand.php

Answer (score -2):

In the file path: /vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Commands/JWTGenerateCommand.php

Add public function

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->fire();
}
```